# How to change japanese keymap from QWERTZ to QWERTY on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, japanese

I'm native German speaker so the keyboard layout I'm used to is QWERTZ. Since about a year or so I've had the chance to study Japanese and part of it is obviously also writing texts in Japanese. I therefore added the Japanese language to my system and a corresponding keyboard to which I can switch via `Left Alt + Shift` and this works just fine. The only problem I have with it is that the underlying keymap seems to be QWERTY, which can be pretty annoying...

I don't really know how to fix this, but what I basically want is to switch just the Japanese keyboard from QWERTY to QWERTZ. Any idea how this can be achieved?

*Note:* I'm sorry if I misused the word "keymap" and "keyboard layout" here, I'm not really familiar with the right terminology.. If the question is not clear, please let me know, I'll try to explain it better...

Answer (score 4):

This procedure should help:

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to key:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000411`
- Ensure you are on the right key : "Layout Text" should read "Japanese"
- Change the value of "Layout File" from "KBDJPN.DLL" to "KBDGR.DLL"
  (without the quotes)
- Reboot.

If this doesn't help, undo it by returning the value of "KBDJPN.DLL"
(without quotes).

Comment: This method worked for a long time. But since I freshly reinstall Windows 10 Pro 2004 (the 2020 May update), it stops working since. I have tried to change the registry key to "KBDGR.DLL", "KBDGR1.DLL" and "KBDJPN.DLL" to no avail. Strangely, QWERTZ still works for the simplified Chinese input.

Comment: Version 2004 is not yet officially out, so this might yet change. I don't have this version, so cannot test. Search the registry for the value, if it changed place. [RegScanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) is a fast search tool.

Comment: It is officially out already. I installed Goolge Japanese IME and strangely, the registry trick works there (I also tried to change it back and see indeed, the registry change is needed to be QWERTZ even for Goolge ime).

Comment: @dgg32 Just ran into the same issue. In the Windows 10 settings, under the General IME settings, there is a toggle allowing to use the "previous version of Microsoft IME". Enabling it did the trick and allowed me to use QWERTZ!

Answer (score -1):

Follow harrymc's first four steps:

- start regedit
- go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000411`
- do make sure it is the japanese layout
- change `KBDJPN.DLL` to your language (e.g. `KBDGR.DLL`)

---

- then, go to`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters`
- also change this from `kbd101.dll` to your language (e.g. `kbdgr.dll`)
- now reboot.

This change made it work on my machine (MS Win10 Pro v 10.0.19043).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the answer that was awarded a bounty from over three years ago?

Comment: @DarkDiamond On my machine, that solution was insufficient, probably due to a windows update (as others had mentioned). I found a registry entry that worked in combination with that one, so I posted an updated version. I wouldve written a reply, but for three reasons;

1: You cannot make replies with a brand new account,

2: It is more visible as a stand-alone solution, and

3: Since this is an inactive issue with few entries, I figured making a new solution wouldnt make the page cluttered.